# Acceder a datos Json

Tags: json

Estoy tratando de acceder a unos datos del siguiente Json pero no obtengo nada.

Si lo pongo así se me llega la info.

```
{{shippingData.address.addressType}}
```

Pero de esta para acceder a este si ya no me llega nada, como seria la forma correcta de acceder a ese dato?

```
{{shippingData.logisticsInfo[1].selectedSla}}
```

```
"shippingData": {
        "attachmentId": "shippingData",
        "address": {
            "addressType": "residential",
        },
        "logisticsInfo": [
            {
                "itemIndex": 0,
                "selectedSla": "entrega a domicilio",
                "slas": [
                    {
                        "id": "entrega a domicilio",
                        "name": "entrega a domicilio",
                        "deliveryIds": [
                            {
                                "courierId": "1d",
                                "warehouseId": "1",
                                "dockId": "1",
                                "courierName": "TC",
                                "quantity": 1
                            }
                        ],                      
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: es por que solo tienes un elemento por lo que el indice deberia ser 0 {{shippingData.logisticsInfo[0].selectedSla}}

Comment: En el JSON que muestras, `logisticinfo` es un Array que contiene 1 sólo elemento, por lo tanto `logisticinfo[1]` seimpre será `undefined`. En todo caso deberías acceder usando `{{shippingData.logisticsInfo[0].selectedSla}}`, ya que los tipo Array empiezan su índice en 0 y no en 1. Saludos

Comment: lo puse en [0] pero tampoco llega nada :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo el siguiente JSON de ejemplo (el tuyo no me valida):

```
{
    "shippingData": {
        "attachmentId": "shippingData",
        "address": {
            "addressType": "residential"
        },
        "logisticsInfo": [{
            "itemIndex": 0,
            "selectedSla": "entrega a domicilio",
            "slas": [{
                "id": "entrega a domicilio",
                "name": "entrega a domicilio",
                "deliveryIds": [{
                    "courierId": "1d",
                    "warehouseId": "1",
                    "dockId": "1",
                    "courierName": "TC",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Y usando python como ejemplo con el que procesaré el json:

```
# Importo el módulo:
import json

# Guardo el nombre del fichero:
filename = 'example.json'

# Abro el fichero, cargo los datos del json en la variable data y cierro el file handle:
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

El **resultado**:

```
{'shippingData': {'attachmentId': 'shippingData', 'address': {'addressType': 'residential'}, 'logisticsInfo': [{'itemIndex': 0, 'selectedSla': 'entrega a domicilio', 'slas': [{'id': 'entrega a domicilio', 'name': 'entrega a domicilio', 'deliveryIds': [{'courierId': '1d', 'warehouseId': '1', 'dockId': '1', 'courierName': 'TC', 'quantity': 1}]}]}]}}
```

**Podría acceder a la key `selectedSla`** de la siguiente forma:

```
print(data['shippingData']['logisticsInfo'][0]['selectedSla'])
```

**Que me da como resultado**:

```
entrega a domicilio
```

Ten en cuenta que al acceder a `logisticsInfo` tienes que acceder al primer contenido de este por los corchetes.